# Access the property of a JSON object

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to access property of a JSON object called `date` in Angular 6. I assigned to variable to it but this appear like undefined.

This is my code:

```
getHistorial(dateB:string, dateA:string){

     this._HistorialService.query(dateB, dateA).subscribe(response=>{debugger
        if(response.Historial){

            var test =response.Historial.fecha
            console.log(test);
        }
        error=>{
          console.log(<any>error);
        }
    });
  }
```

I'm trying this:

```
var test = response.Historial.map(fecha);
var test = response.Historial.pipe(map(fecha));
```

I'm using Angular 6, and an API on Node.

this is the json with the whole response

```
Historial: Array(7)
0: {_id: "5c8d7ede252e5631b030a59c", nombre: "urea", cantidad: 5, unidadMedida: "Unds", fecha: "201903161755", …}
1: {_id: "5c8d7eea252e5631b030a59d", nombre: "urea", cantidad: 58, unidadMedida: "Unds", fecha: "201903161755", …}
2: {_id: "5c8d8088252e5631b030a5a0", nombre: "urea", cantidad: 5, unidadMedida: "Kgs", fecha: "201903161802", …}
3: {_id: "5c8d8091252e5631b030a5a1", nombre: "urea", cantidad: 51, unidadMedida: "Kgs", fecha: "201903161802", …}
4: {_id: "5c8d85ef252e5631b030a5a2", nombre: "urea", cantidad: 7, unidadMedida: "Kgs", fecha: "201903161825", …}
5: {_id: "5c8df263252e5631b030a5a4", nombre: "sulfato de amonio", cantidad: 8, unidadMedida: "Kgs", fecha: "201903170208", …}
6: {_id: "5c8ea35832c85438bcecd7ed", nombre: "urea", cantidad: 2, unidadMedida: "Kgs", fecha: "201903171443", …}
```

Comment: did you try console the response

Comment: what your "console.log(test);" shows in the console?

Comment: yes, the response is ok, i'm gonna update the post with the respose

Comment: what you are trying to do wouldn't work since response isn't an observable anymore.  In order to use any operator you need to apply it before the subscribe.  Another option might be, to use `Observable.from(response)` ... all the rest of the operators and subscribe again

Comment: I would suggest taking some time to better understand RxJs, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL55RiY5tL51pHpagYcrN9ubNLVXF8rGVi and https://www.learnrxjs.io/ are great places to spruce up your observable game

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do wouldn't work since response isn't an observable anymore. In order to use any operator you need to apply it before the subscribe. Another option might be, to use Observable.from(response) ... all the rest of the operators and subscribe again

I've created a small stackblitz here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-j4sonn?embed=1&file=index.ts

you could do something like this to get a list of "fecha's" e.g:

```
getHistorial(dateB:string, dateA:string){

 this._HistorialService.query(dateB, dateA)
 .pipe(map(results => results.fecha))
 .subscribe(fecha =>{
    if(fecha){
        console.log(fecha);
    }
    error=>{
      console.log(<any>error);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: hi @jcuypers, i tryed it and "fecha" appear undefined

Comment: @EstivetGiraldo: sorry was a bit too fast without checking my code.  I've updated it. please check it + stackblitz.